# Using a geojson with highmaps

Tags: highcharts, geojson, highmaps

I want to display some data about San Francisco using highmaps but there is no maps of the different neighborhoods in SF in the highmaps library so I found an geojson of San Francisco wich was validate by this site: [geojson validator](http://geojsonlint.com/) but when I use the highmaps validator he doesn't read it: [the highmap validator](http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/xbzxfx2L/)

```
$('#run').click(function () {     
var geojson = $.parseJSON($('#geojson').val());

// Initiate the chart
$('#container').slideDown().highcharts('Map', {
    series: [{
        mapData: geojson
    }]
   });    
});
```

This is my geojson: [pastebin code](http://pastebin.com/hhNA32xV).
Do you know why it's not validated by highmaps but it's validate by the geojson validator? Or do you know a San Francisco map which will be validated by highmaps?

Comment: Please check how you can create custom maps here: http://www.highcharts.com/docs/maps/custom-geojson-maps

Comment: @SebastianBochan Can u do an answer, like that I can close the subject. So highchart doesn't use the official GeoJson format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider importing your .geojson into [QGis](http://www.qgis.org), then exporting it out again. In my experience any .geojson that QGis produces is usable by Highmaps. Also see this tutorial [Creating custom geojson maps for Highmaps with QGis](http://www.independent-software.com/creating-custom-geojson-maps-for-highmaps-with-qgis/).